# How to serve server-side scripts for front-end frameworks like angular

Tags: angular, xampp, angular-cli, server-side

How do I serve server-side scripts for front-end frameworks like angular

I am building a web application in Angular 5 using CLI. I haven't built the server-side components so am using mock-data for now because I am having problems making calls to server (php files) work via *relative urls*. 
Am serving the file with CLI like `ng serve --open` and it is hosted on `localhost:4200`. As far as I know, it does now parse PHP code and some people suggest I serve it through XAMPP. I find this confusing because it will be served on another port e.g `localhost:8080` meaning that I have to specify the full url like so `localhost:8080/api/products/24` for it to work. Is there any other way I can do this so that my url will just be `api/products/24`? Because when generating production files, that `localhost:8080` present in the url will cause a problem.

Comment: see this [proxying support](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use environment's config files so that you can specify the api's URL.

That way, when you use the API from your service, you use the config's value instead of hardcoded one

**environment.ts**

```
{
  apiUrl: "http://mydevelopmenturl
}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
{
  apiUrl: "http://myrealurl
}
```

When you need to make an API call, use the URL from the config

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

getAccounts()
{
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/accounts`);
}
```

When you do a build, specify the environment to use

```
ng build --environment=...
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files